# Extension method for DataRow object .NET

Tags: asp.net, vb.net, extension-methods

Currently, I've written extension method for `DataRow` that converts row value to a specific type of object, method looks like:

```
<ExtensionAttribute> _
Public Function GetValue(Of T)(row As DataRow, columnName As String) As T
    'IF TABLE DOESN'T CONTAIN COLUMN RETURN DEFAULT OF T
    If Not row.Table.Columns.Contains(columnName) Then 
        Return Activator.CreateInstance(Of T)()

    'IF ROW IS DB NULL RETURN DEFAULT OF T
    If row(columnName) Is DBNull.Value Then 
        Return Activator.CreateInstance(Of T)()
       'RETURN T

    Return CType(row(columnName), T)
 End Function
```

My question is how to improve this method that a user can set default value of object (T) (eg. for boolean type that doesn't return default FALSE value than TRUE). Sure it will be an optional parameter of extension method.

Comment: Are you aware that there is already such a function in the framework called `T Field<T>(this DataRow row, string columnName)`? See: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb360891(v=vs.90).aspx

Comment: @Magnus: ... which even supports nullable types which is better than using the default value of  a given type (what OP does).

Answer (score 1):

Couldn't a user-supplied default simply be a parameter on the method?  Something like this:

```
<ExtensionAttribute> _
 Public Function GetValue(Of T)(row As DataRow, columnName As String, defaultValue As T) As T
     If Not row.Table.Columns.Contains(columnName) Then
         Return defaultValue
     If row(columnName) Is DBNull.Value Then
         Return defaultValue
    Return CType(row(columnName), T)
End Function
```

Setting up an optional parameter might be tricky between potential value and reference types of `T`.  You may put some constraints on `T`.  Though if you keep both methods then the parameter is effectively still optional because it's an overload of the method, which may be easier.